# How to select and deselect multiple tableview cells in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, select

I need to select multiple tableview cells and if i click that again then it should deselect. so tried below code but got error

How to append selected rows `arrSelectedRowsBuy` and when tap again then how to deselect that cell from arrSelectedRowsBuy. please guide me

```
var arrSelectedRowsBuy:[Int] = []
var selectedIndexes : Set<Int> = []


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row) {
    self.arrSelectedRowsBuy.remove(at: eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id ?? 0)
    print("removed array \(arrSelectedRowsBuy)")
}
else {
    self.arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id ?? 0)
    print("added array \(arrSelectedRowsBuy)")
}
}
```

now i am not able to remove deselected cell id from `arrSelectedRowsBuy` if i tap second time then id adding second time. **if i tap second time how to remove added row**

> added array [1, 3, 3, 2, 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if the `selectedIndexes` contains the index of the selected item using `if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row) { ... }`, but you are not updating `selectedIndexes` with the actual index anywhere. So, the `if` condition always fails and the `else` block will be executed.

Try this:

```
if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row) {
    self.arrSelectedRowsBuy.remove(at: eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id ?? 0)
    // Add this
    if let index = selectedIndexes.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row) {
        selectedIndexes.remove(at: index)
    }
} else {
    self.arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id ?? 0)
    // Add this
    selectedIndexes.append(indexPath.row)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a set of selectedIndexes

```
var selectedIndexes : Set<Int> = []
```

then in didselect method check every time if selectedIndexes contains current indexPaht.row. If it contains then unselect it and remove it from selectedIndexes set otherwise select it and insert it to selectedIndexes

Comment: i have tried your code.. now i am unable to delete row if i tap second time.

Comment: i have edited my code with your code change.. can you guide me

Comment: when you will tap second time first you need to remove indexPath.row from set like that `selectedIndexes.remove(indexPath.row)`
and do other stuff what you need

Comment: i dont want to remove `indexPath.row` i want to remove `eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id`

Comment: can you update total code.. i dont understand your code

Comment: selectedIndexes.remove(indexPath.row) do you think this will work?

Comment: "arrSelectedRowsBuy" does it contain unique value ?
if it is then update arrSelectedRowsBuy to Set.
Otherwise you have to run a loop to check arrSelectedRowsBuy contains the id, if is then have to remove it

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to handle multiple selection yourself. `UITableView` has an `allowsMultipleSelection` property for this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614938-allowsmultipleselection

You will receive separate delegate callbacks when rows are selected or de-selected. Your code is also keeping track of some model object identifiers which you could keep doing in the select/deselect delegate methods or just ask the table view for `indexPathsForSelectedRows`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows

If you do want to keep an up-to-date array of model identifiers you need to fix your code. You are inserting an identifier at the end of the array but deleting an identifier by the position in the array. That will remove the wrong item or simply crash when you try and remove by a row index that is higher than the number of items in your array. That’s probably worth a separate question.

Comment: can you please guide me to add and remove selected row value in `self.arrSelectedRowsBuy.append(eventListData?.result?.events?[indexPath.row].id ?? 0)`

Comment: You need to remove the entry with a specific `id`, not the entry at the `id`’th index in the array. And you shouldn’t be adding/removing 0 if you can’t find one.